# Execute function for each element checked

Tags: php, javascript, html, function, checkbox

I have a couple of checkboxes and I want to execute a function for each of the elements marked as checked. How can I do this?

In my particular case, I think this might be a little bit easier, because the checkboxes are constructed like this:

```
        $get_json_values=json_decode($json_string,true);
        foreach ($get_json_values as $key=>$getlikes) {  
          if($getlikes['type']=='like') {
          ?>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $getlikes['name'] ?>" value="<?php echo $getlikes['id'] ?>" checked> 
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $getlikes['id']; ?>" target="_top">
              <?php echo $getlikes['name'] ?> </a>
            </div>
        <?php
      }}
       ?>
```

So I think it should look like this:

```
function doIfChecked()
{
  foreach ($get_json_values as $key=>$getlikes) {
       if($getlikes['type']=='like'&&<sequence that checks if checkbox is checked>)
           {//do stuff}
          }
}
```

Can  anyone please help?

---

Thanks to Julian H. Lam, I found a good answer, **but** my problem is that for each of the elements , I need to do a request to the server (like a page on facebook), but I can't put any php inside javascript.

So, how could I do that since php is not allowed inside js?

Answer (score 3):

Using javascript:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),
    numCheckboxes = checkboxes.length,
    x;

for(x=0;x<numCheckboxes;x++) {
    if (checkboxes[x].checked === true) {
        // add code here to be done for each checked element
        // you can refer to the checked element by calling "checkboxes[x]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. Just getting started in webdev and I'm not always sure when should I add php and when shoud I put js. Thank you